# How to create an event inside a thread without using Dispatcher

Tags: c#, multithreading, class

Right now i am writing a program where i have to use threads. The thread starts inside of a class. I want to code it so that every time a thread get new info to display it puts it in a rich text box. But i don'at want to use something like this:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
{
    ...// your code here.
}));
```

Is there a way of making a event, that will be raised every time the thread has new info?

Here i will make some pseudo code,  hopefully you can understand:

```
//CLASS X
Thread
{
    info = new info available()!;
    RAISE_EVENT RECIVE_NEW_INFO (info);
}

//ON MAIN FORM
private void RECIVE_NEW_INFO(object sender, EventArgs e, string data)
{
    richtextbox1.add(data);
}
```

Comment: Introduce a class to _hide_ your thread and attach event handler in your main form. Or expose an interface in your main form to raise events from within your thread. But whatever you do you will always need to use Dispatcher because UI can't (generally) be updated from any other thread than the _main_ one.

Comment: Like @AdrianoRepetti said, either you need to call the `Dispatcher.Invoke` on an event from the thread method **or** you'll have to add the info to a queue and check it with a timer on the gui thread.

Comment: So what ever in do i will always have to use Dispatcher, correct?

Comment: Hm ok, then i believe i will stick with what is simple. If someone wants to use the comments above to write a answer, please do. So that i can mark it has correct.

Comment: I have also edited the question name.